# Berge's proof that M is maximum in G <--> G contains no M-augmenting path

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation

This is a question about the first part of the proof of Theorem 5.1 in "Graph Theory with Applications" by J.A. Bondy and U.S.R. Murty, 1976, North-Holland, page 70.

The strategy is to suppose a maximum matching $M$ with an $M$-augmenting path and show a larger matching $M'$, violating the assumption that $M$ is maximum.

Suppose M-augmenting is $v_0 v_1 ... v_{2m + 1}$.  (Clearly $v_0 v_1$ is not in $M$, and also $v_{2m} v_{2m+1}$ is not in M.)  Defines $M' = \{v_0 v_1, v_2 v_3, ..., v_{2m} v_{2m+1}\} \cup M - \{v_1 v_2, v_3v_4, ..., v_{2m-1}v_{2m}\}$. Now $|M'| = |M| + 1.$

Question.  Why must we subtract $\{v_1 v_2, v_3v_4, ..., v_{2m-1}v_{2m}\}$?  I can't see how this is necessary. These edges are the edges of $M$.  We could then define $M' = \{v_0 v_1, v_2 v_3, ..., v_{2m} v_{2m+1}\} - M$.

The answer must that there might be more edges in $M$ which we cannot afford not to take in M'.  I'm thinking that an example to show this is a disconnected graph, where in one component we have the $M$-augmenting path and in another component $C$ we just a maximum matching $M_C$.  Then in order to have M' maximum in the disconnected graph, we must take all edges $M_C$.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Why must we subtract $\{v_1 v_2, v_3v_4, ..., v_{2m-1}v_{2m}\}$?  I can't see how this is necessary. These edges are the edges of $M$.

In order to avoid in $M’$ edges with common vertices. For instance, if $M’$ contains an edge $v_0v_1$ then it cannot contain the edge $v_1v_2$.

> We could then define $M' = \{v_0 v_1, v_2 v_3, ..., v_{2m} v_{2m+1}\} - M$. ... The answer must that there might be more edges in $M$ which we cannot afford not to take in M'.

In general, $M$ can contain edges which are disjoint with the found $M$-augmenting path, which we have to retain, so, in general, we cannot put $M' = \{v_0 v_1, v_2 v_3, ..., v_{2m} v_{2m+1}\} - M$.